# Showing images in chain one after one issue

Tags: jquery

My div has many images like

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="images/flowing-rock.jpg" alt="Flowing Rock" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" />
<img src="images/grass-blades.jpg" alt="Grass Blades" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" />
<img src="images/ladybug.jpg" alt="Ladybug" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" />
<img src="images/lightning.jpg" alt="Lightning" width="580" height="360" title="" alt="" />
</div>
```

I want to show one image at a time and after some time another images will be shown but my jQuery code is not working. What is the problem

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {
    $('#gallery img').css({ opacity: 0.0 });
    $('#gallery img:first').css({ opacity: 1.0 });
    setInterval('gallery()', 2000);
}

 function gallery() {
    var current = ($('#gallery img.show') ? $('#gallery img.show') : $('#gallery img').first());
    var next = current.next().length > 0  ? current.next() : $('#gallery img').first();

    next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
    .addClass('show')
    .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000);

    current.animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 1000).removeClass('show');
}
```

Can anyone please rectify my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "next"-variable is assigned an HTMLImageElement which does not understand jQuery-functions. In stead of using

```
$('#gallery img').get(0)
```

use this

```
$('#gallery img').first()
```

If you do this in all places, it should work (at least it did here) :-) The updated jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  slideShow();
});

function slideShow() {
    $('#gallery img').css({ opacity: 0.0 });
    $('#gallery img:first').css({ opacity: 1.0 });
    setInterval('gallery()', 2000);
}

function gallery() {
    var current = ($('#gallery img.show') ? $('#gallery img.show') : $('#gallery     img').first());
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('caption')) ? $('#gallery img').first() : current.next()) : $('#gallery img').first());

    next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000);

    current.animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 1000).removeClass('show');
}
```